# Setting alarm notification for Dates Arrays

Tags: android, alarmmanager, localnotification

I am trying to create local notification that's declenche before a given date by 2 hours , 4 hours and at this given date. This is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
private void alarmnotification(String notificationid, String type, long timemills) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timemills);



    AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArrayd = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        long timemfills = timemills - 7200000*i ;
        Calendar calendadr = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendadr.setTimeInMillis(timemfills);

        Calendar calendad0r = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendad0r.setTimeInMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+calendadr.getTimeInMillis());


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPublisher.class);
        intent.putExtra("type", type);
        intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationid);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, i, intent, 0);

        mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, timemfills, pendingIntent);

        intentArrayd.add(pendingIntent);


    }
}
```

And this is My notification Publisher Code :
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notificationId";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "type";
private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get id & message from intent.
    String notificationId = intent.getStringExtra("notificationId");
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("type");
    // When notification is tapped, call MainActivity.
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
    mainIntent.putExtra("retour", message);
    mainIntent.putExtra("element_id", notificationId);
    mainIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);

    NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Prepare notification.
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icoapp_and)
            .setContentTitle(notificationId)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    // Notify
    Random rand = new Random();
    myNotificationManager.notify(rand.nextInt(), builder.build());


}
```

}

The problem is that I don't get any notifications at all.

Comment: can you add NotificationPublisher code ?

Comment: thid is My on Receive Method:

Comment: PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);
        NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icoapp_and)
                .setContentTitle(notificationId)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

Comment: Random rand = new Random();
        myNotificationManager.notify(rand.nextInt(), builder.build());

Comment: kindly attach the code to question by editing

Comment: the broadcast looking fine, i think there is some issue with alarm manager time.
do one thing first just create a broadcast which will trigger after 2 min just to check the broadcast.
i

Comment: if i put after 2 minutes without the loop for it worke, but when i put the loop it doesnt,

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, you should create a Notification Channel to get the notification.

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

For the full documentation, please follow this link:
[Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: the problem is not with  the android version, because i did receive the notification.when i delete the loop for,

Comment: Okay, that's another problem, but at least you need to check in case your user running Android 8.0 or higher.  Btw, try to log the result of `timemfills` and convert it on this website [currentmillis](https://currentmillis.com/). See if the time is correctly set.

Comment: My problem is : I have an Arrays of interview dates , and i have   to alerted  the user befor each date  by 6 hours then 4 hours the two hours .Any help .

Comment: Have you tried to log the time? Make sure it set correctly before 4 hours and 6 hours.

Comment: the first thing i did , i convert the time to date and print it in the log  its correct, and the program enter in the loop but it didn t send the notif ,i don t know why ,

Comment: and this is the time ,i print in the log                                                  
  D/caledarrrr: Thu Jun 13 16:45:50 GMT+01:00 2019 time0
 D/caledarrrr: Thu Jun 13 14:45:50 GMT+01:00 2019 time2
 D/caledarrrr: Thu Jun 13 12:45:50 GMT+01:00 2019 time4

Answer (score 0):

Try with that. As this will trigger alarm on time send to function, and before 2 hours of that time, and 4 hours

and dont forget to add channel as it would not work in Orea or above

```
    private void alarmnotification(String notificationid, String type, long timemills) 
    {
    Random rand = new Random();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timemills);


    AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArrayd = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    Calendar calendadr = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                // setting alarm on the specified Date
                calendadr.setTimeInMillis(timemills);
                intent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
                intent.putExtra("type", type);
                intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationid);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, rand, intent, 0);
                mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, calendadr.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                intentArrayd.add(pendingIntent);
                break;
            case 2:
                // setting alarm 2 hours earlier of the date
                calendadr.setTimeInMillis(timemills);
                // deducting 2 hours
                calendadr.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2);
                intent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
                intent.putExtra("type", type);
                intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationid);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, rand, intent, 0);
                mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, calendadr.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                intentArrayd.add(pendingIntent);
                break;
            case 3:
                // setting alarm 2 hours earlier of the date
                calendadr.setTimeInMillis(timemills);
                // deducting 2 hours
                intent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
                calendadr.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -4);
                intent.putExtra("type", type);
                intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationid);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, rand, intent, 0);
                mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, calendadr.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                intentArrayd.add(pendingIntent);

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I  comment the part of   intentArrayd.add(pendingIntent);and  i set 0 in the place of rand , and its work fine ,